# Decomposition of a martingale into a semimartingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

The definition of [semimartingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimartingale) follows from Wikipedia.

I want to find a semimartingale representation for the process$$ F_t=\int_0^t f(t-s)dB_s,$$where $f$ is a continuous bounded variation function and $B_s$ the standard Brownian motion.

I tried using integration by parts and found$$ F_t=f(0)B_t-\int_0^tB_s\dfrac{\partial f(t-s)}{\partial s}ds,$$which gives $$dF_t=f(0)B_t+B_tf'(0)dt, $$but $B_tf'(0)$ is obviously not of bounded variation. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Depending on the design of $f(t-s)$ you might have a problem in the stochastic integral, because $dtdB=0$. Is the design of such function a given assignment?

Comment: @NicholasLP Yes it is a given assignment

Comment: Do you have any other information on the structure of $f$?

Comment: Also, do you know if $F_t$ is assigned as a semimartingale already?

Comment: @NicholasLP I think it is already assgined as a semimartingale and that's why I'm a bit reluctant about your solution.

Comment: Does the bounded variation of $f$ imply L2 convergence?

Comment: @NicholasLP Yes $f$ is a  square integrable function on $[0,T]$ where the process is defined

Comment: Last questions: 1) is f(t−s) Fs−adapted or does it depend on Ft too? 2) is f deterministic or it can be stochastic?

Comment: @NicholasLP $f$ is deterministic therefore it is adapted to both $F_s$ and $F_t$

Comment: I updated my solution. Hopefully, it will help you. GL

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f$ is an L2 converging deterministic integrand function. To transform $F$ into a semimartingale, one could apply the Girsanov theorem and change the probability measure of your original process $F$.

To apply the Girsanov theorem, you need to define an adapted process $\Theta(t)$ such that, defining the Radon-Nikodym derivative

$$
Z_t = \exp{\{-\int_0^t{\Theta(s)dB_s}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t{\Theta(s)^2ds}\}},
$$

$$
\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}\int_0^t{\Theta(s)^2Z_t^2ds}<\infty.
$$

Then, defining

$$
\tilde{B}_t=B_t+\int_0^t{\Theta(s)ds},
$$

$\tilde{B_t}$ is a Brownian motion.

Going back to your process,

$$
F_t=\int_0^t f(t-s)dB_s
$$

assuming that $f(t-s)$ is a deterministic function of time, integrable, and $\int_0^t f(t-s)^2dt<\infty$, I suggest to write

$$
F_t=\int_0^s f(t-u)dB_u+\int_s^t f(t-u)dB_u.
$$

Then, fixing a terminal $t$ for $f$, one could write the following new function:

$$
g(s|t)=g(s)=\int_0^s f(t-u)dB_u.
$$

Because of the assumed properties of $f$, in particular being of bounded variation, square integrable deterministic function of $u$, given $t$, $g(s)$ is an Ito integral and a martingale. For this reason, it is possible to write it in differential form as:

$$
dg(u)=f(t-u)d\tilde{B}_u.
$$

But from the Girsanov theorem expressed in differential form we have

$$
dB_u=d\tilde{B}_u-\Theta(s)du,
$$

so that

$$
dg(u)=f(t-u)dB_u=f(t-u)[d\tilde{B}_u-\Theta(u)du],
$$

which returns the semimartingale under the new probability measure as

$$
dg(u)=-\Theta(u)f(t-u)du + f(t-u)d\tilde{B}_u,
$$

which has an integral representation

$$
g(s)=g(0)-\int_0^s \Theta(u)f(t-u)du+\int_0^s f(t-u)dB_u.
$$

Thus, since, as $s\rightarrow t$, $g(s)=g(s|t)\rightarrow F_t$, one could write a semimartingale representation for $F$ as

$$
F_t=g(0)-\int_0^t \Theta(s)f(t-s)ds+\int_0^t f(t-s)dB_s,
$$

or

$$
F_t=F_0-\int_0^t \Theta(s)f(t-s)ds+\int_0^t f(t-s)dB_s.
$$

Comment: can you please elaborate how to apply the Girsanov theorem in more details?